# Hierarchy in ER and OO Model

Tags: java, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, database-design, relational-database

So, it might be a very fundamental question, but I'm pretty confusing right now...

It's all about Element and ElementCategory: an element belongs to a category, a categoty can have many elements - a straightforward one to many relationship.

At the database level, I have two tables:

> Element(element_id, category_id, element_name)
>
> Category(category_id, category_name)

At the application level (Java), I would have:

> class Element { int id; String name; Category category; }
>
> class Category { int id; String name; Collection elements; }

My question: did I have the right approach, both at the database level and application level? What kind of relationship is that in OOD? *has-a, is-a, inheritance, generalization relationship or whatsoever...*

Thanks in advance for any constructive comments and answers.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Samuel that your database tables look correct.

- The database relationship looking from the Element end is one to one - an element must have one and only one Category.
- The database relationship looking from the Category end is zero to many. A category may have zero to many Elements.

The only restriction on adding new records is that the Category must be added before any element that is in that category.

On the OOD/Java side, things get a little more interesting.

- Your Element class is fine. It reflects the underlying database table. There is a *has a* relationship to Category. Any good Java ORM will map this nicely.
- In general, the Category class should not have a collection of Elements, as the performance will suffer. If you let the ORM populate this collection, then retrieving a single Element by ID will load the single Category for that element, and the ORM will then load all Elements that are in that Category to populate the collection. This is almost always not what you want. There are work-arounds involving lazy loading, but these can be messy to use when the database access layer is on a remote server (e.g. As in almost all web apps).
- If you need to lookup elements by Category, it is usually limited to a single category at a time (e.g. Show me all the Lamborginis we have in stock), and often needs a specialist SQL query (e.g. Show me all the 2016 red Toyotas in stock). To do these queries efficiently, your database service layer will need specialist functions that return a collection of Elements.

So my advice is to remove the collection of Elements from Category, and add database queries to handle any use case that needs to lookup elements by category. Note that a good ORM (MyBatis is my favorite) will still handle the mapping from the query results to the collection of Elements.

Answer (score -1):

You have a circular dependency between `Category` and `Element` in your code. Meaning `Category` depends on `Element` and `Element` depends on `Category`. This could cause problems trying to populate this structure from the database:

```
1. Populate element A
2. Populate element A's category
3. Populate element A's category's elements (which includes A)
4. Populate element A's category's elements' categories
5. Populate element A's category's elements' categories' elements
etc.
```

It also creates an ambiguity of how you should update an element's category. Should you change `Element.category`, or should you add/remove the element from `Category.elements`? To avoid these kinds of problems you should make the relationship unidirectional.

Your tables have a unidirectional relationship and they look good. To fix your code models you just need to remove `elements` from `Category`.

```
class Element { int id; String name; Category category; }

class Category { int id; String name; }
```

Comment: Thank you @Samuel. Please kindly explain what do you mean by "circular dependency" and why the relationship should be unidirectional?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some of the problems with a circular relationship

Comment: Thanks again @Samuel. So how about `class Element { int id; String name; }

class Category { int id; String name; Collection<Element> elements; }` ?

Comment: Yes that would be unidirectional as well. If you were to adopt this approach I would suggest changing your table structure so you have `category`, `element`, and `category_element`. `element` would only have `id` and `name`, and `category_element` would store the relationship between the two tables.

Comment: Would changing the table structure as you suggested allow a many to many relationship between element and category, which in this case isn't permitted?

Comment: Yes, you would need a unique constraint on `category_element` on `element_id` to prevent an element being in two categories. But that's probably an reason not to model the relationship from `category -> element`  but `element -> category`. The code snippet I've put in my answer is a clear one to many relationship, but if you do `Category { Collection<Element> elements; }` it's ambiguous what the relationship is.

Comment: Most ORMs I have used have absolutely no problem with bi-directional relationships of this sort.